# Angular - updating fragment without a page reload

Tags: angular

I have a `TabGroup` component containing a number of `Tab` components. The selected tab is controlled / managed using the `fragment` in the URL.

Whenever a tab is selected I do (in the TabGroup):

```js
  ...
  @ContentChildren(Tab) public tabs: QueryList<Tab>;

  constructor(private readonly route: ActivatedRoute, private readonly router: Router) {}

  setActiveTab(tab: Tab) {
    // set all tabs to not selected.
    this.tabs.forEach((currTab) => (currTab.active = false));
    // update the `fragment` in the url (but don't change the page)
    this.router.navigate(['.'], { relativeTo: this.route, fragment: tab.key });
  }
  ...
```

The issue I'm having is that whenever the tab is clicked the whole page reloads. Obviously the tab content should update but not the whole page.

These are my app router options:

```js
   RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'ignore',
      relativeLinkResolution: 'corrected',
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
   }),
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: You need to add `useHash: true` in your router option to allow hash.

Comment: `useHash` doesn't seem to make any different. Also, the actual fragment works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to do it in Angular 16:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

  ...
  constructor(private router: Router, private location: Location) {}

  updateFragment() {
    const urlTree = this.router.createUrlTree([], { fragment });
    this.location.go(urlTree.toString());
  }
  ...
```

This will change the hash in the url without reloading the page.